# Managing javascript / css dependancies?

Tags: javascript, files

I know you can add css / js with the drupal_add_css() or drupal_add_js(). Is there a way to define dependancies ?

*Use Case Example:*

> I need a custom tabs/carousel jquery plugin working. I need jquery and
>   jquery ui to load first. In order to ensure that i'd like it to load
>   after jquery and jquery ui.

How would one do that?

Also, is there a way to declare if a script / library is already loaded? i.e. if i load two jquery (1.4 vs 1.8.1) libraries it'll conflict.

Or would this discussion be better suited for the drupal core issue queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what [hook_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) is for.  You define your library

```
function mymodule_library ()
{
    $path = drupal_get_path("module", "mymodule");

    $libraries = array();

    $libraries["mymodule_util"] = array(
        "title" => "MyModule Utilities", 
        "version" => "0.0",
        "js" => array(
            $path . '/UTIL.js' => array(),
        ),

        'weight' => -10,
    );

    return $libraries;
}
```

You can add CSS and declare dependencies, if needed.

Then you say you want to use it

```
drupal_add_library("mymodule", "mymodule_util", TRUE);
```

This ensures all of the dependencies get loaded exactly once.

Check out [drupal_add_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7) for more details.  The core jQuery UI components are loaded this way, too.  The module is `system` and the names all begin with `ui.`, eg `ui.scroller`.

I would also check out [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) to upgrade things so you stay in sync with that other jQuery plugins need.

Answer (score 0):

This is built into drupal core with the [`hook_library`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7).

This functionality isn't smart enough to figure out if you want to load two versions of the same thing, but I can't see a generics usage of loading different versions of the same library. Also with regard to jQuery and the version numbers, are you confusing jQuery and jQuery UI which can live side by side (has different version numbers).